# Using a defined function to implement some equations

Tags: python

Please I need your help, I am trying to write a PYTHON code that uses  a defined function with name calcExcelDate to implement some equations of excel date equivalent for a given date specified as:

- year (a 4 digit integer from 1900 to 9999);
- month (a 1 or 2 digit integer from 1 to 12);
- day (a 1 or 2 digit integer from 1 to 31, depending on month).

I defined the function and used 3 for loops that specify the above given ranges of year, month and day. But how can use that function to implement the follwoing equations:

```
y_2 = year - 1900
em = math.floor((14 - month) / 12)
y_3 = y_2 - em
m_2 = month + 12 * em
I_ = 1 + min(y_3, 0) + math.floor(y_3 / 4) - math.floor(y_3 / 100) + math.floor((y_3 + 300) / 400)
d_1 = math.floor(-1.63 + (m_2 - 1) * 30.6)
d_2 = day + y_3 * 365 + I_ + d_1
```

My code so far:

```
import time
import math


DAYS = ("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
FULL_MONTHS = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")


mm_ = tuple(str(date) for date in range(2013-10-17, 2100-01-01))    # a tuple of character strings containing dates in the date range Excel supports,
                                                                    # such as ("2013-Oct-17", "2100-01-01")
print mm_


def calcExcelDate(year, month, day):

  for year in range(1900, 10000):
    for month in range(1, 13):
      for day in range(1, 32):
        y_2 = year - 1900
        em = math.floor((14 - month) / 12)
        y_3 = y_2 - em
        m_2 = month + 12 * em
        I_ = 1 + min(y_3, 0) + math.floor(y_3 / 4) - math.floor(y_3 / 100)
                           + math.floor((y_3 + 300) / 400)
        d_1 = math.floor(-1.63 + (m_2 - 1) * 30.6)
        d_2 = day + y_3 * 365 + I_ + d_1


xx_ = calcExcelDate(2010, 10, 1)
print xx_
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as output from `calcExcelDate(2010,10,1)`? I don't think you need to loop over all `year`/`month`/`day` (especially since that just overwrites the `year`/`month`/`day` you pass into the function). So deleting the three for loops is probably the first step, and just leave the equations, but I don't really know what you want returned. Does `d_2` contain the final answer you want?

Comment: Agreed.  The word "function" typically means some relation between input and output.  It looks like the input will be some date.  What's the output you want?  What are the concrete **examples** you've done by hand to check whether or not your code is computing the values you expect?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this it would be better to use the standard library [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) as the interface for the dates and times that you wish to handle and then convert them to Excel serial dates as required.

The following code shows how `datetime` dates are converted to Excel dates in the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org) module.

```
def _convert_date_time(self, dt_obj):
    # We handle datetime .datetime, .date and .time objects but convert
    # them to datetime.datetime objects and process them in the same way.
    if isinstance(dt_obj, datetime.datetime):
        pass
    elif isinstance(dt_obj, datetime.date):
        dt_obj = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(dt_obj.toordinal())
    elif isinstance(dt_obj, datetime.time):
        dt_obj = datetime.datetime.combine(self.epoch, dt_obj)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unknown or unsupported datetime type")

    # Convert a Python datetime.datetime value to an Excel date number.
    delta = dt_obj - self.epoch
    excel_time = (delta.days
                  + (float(delta.seconds)
                     + float(delta.microseconds) / 1E6)
                  / (60 * 60 * 24))

    # Special case for datetime where time only has been specified and
    # the default date of 1900-01-01 is used.
    if dt_obj.isocalendar() == (1900, 1, 1):
        excel_time -= 1

    # Account for Excel erroneously treating 1900 as a leap year.
    if not self.date_1904 and excel_time > 59:
        excel_time += 1

    return excel_time
```

The advantage of using `datetime` is that you have a standard interface with a variety of methods for parsing strings into dates or times:

```
my_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-01-23', '%Y-%m-%d')
```